# Strange behavior of Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse with CDT plugin for my C/C++ development. And I use MinGW compiler. Environment Path set properly. All the setting done properly in Eclipse. While editing the source code its working fine but after compilation when I try to execute the source code sometimes it says it cannot open the .exe file or sometimes doesn't show anything when there is some input to take. When I stop the execution pressing the red button program gets executed completely with default values.

But everything is fine if I compile and run the same source code using notepad and the command prompt. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: How exactly do you start debugging? If you are just pressing debug button it will try to launch executable corresponding to the current file and most likely will fail to do so if you have some library header file opened. So you should launch your program by selecting debug / or launch configuration corresponding to that project.

Comment: I suspect (based on limited information) that the problem you are facing is two-fold.

1. The exe is in use when building sometimes, causing an error
2. If you are doing reading/writing to the console, you need to be aware of buffering. The console within Eclipse does not have same behaviour as a normal terminal and will buffer the input and output differently.

Comment: Please post your actual [MCVE] to get more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

A common problem is that if the program is currently executing, the program file is opened by the system and cannot be reopened for writing by the compiler (or more exactly by the linker). This problem can be easily reproduced by starting the program in debug mode and stop it at a breakpoint. Then, while the process is active, change a line in source and ask for a new build: you will get the error saying that the  exe file cannot be opened.

How to fix: ensure to close any possible execution of the program when the error happens and rebuild